How to convert matfile array to ndarray in rust?
I want to read a matrix inside matfile. The matfile contains 3d array with size (4, 256, 128). The matrix contains Complex number f64. Here is my code that I ran in jupyter notebook with rust kernel:
use std::convert::TryInto;
use matfile::{MatFile};
use std::fs::File;

let file = File::open("some/path/matfile.mat");
let mut radar_mat = MatFile::parse(&file.unwrap()).unwrap();
let radar_arr = radar_mat.find_by_name("data").unwrap().clone();
let nd_arr: ndarray::ArrayD<Complex<f64>> = radar_arr.try_into()?;

I have try to follow the instruction in the docs. However, I got error like this:
[E0277] Error: the trait bound `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<Complex<f64>>, Dim<IxDynImpl>>: From<matfile::Array>` is not satisfied
   ╭─[command_75:1:1]
   │
 5 │ let nd_arr: ndarray::ArrayD<Complex<f64>> = radar_arr.try_into()?;
   │                                                       ────┬───  
   │                                                           ╰───── the trait `From<matfile::Array>` is not implemented for `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<Complex<f64>>, Dim<IxDynImpl>>`, which is required by `matfile::Array: TryInto<_>`
───╯

To give a context about radar_arr variable. I give the screnshoot below:

Anyone know how to fix it?
Thank you

As matfile documents under Crate Feature Flags:

The following crate feature flags can be enabled in your Cargo.toml:

ndarray
Enable conversions between Matfile and ndarray array types



Therefore, in your Cargo.toml, ensure that the matfile dependency has the ndarray feature:
[dependencies]
matfile = { version = "0.4", features = ["ndarray"] }


@ardiantovn: Can you not edit the Cargo.toml file in jupyter notebook?  (In the unlikely event you're not using cargo as a build tool, when building the matfile dependency you'll need to pass the command-line argument --cfg 'feature="ndarray"' to rustc).

I have recreate the code with rs file and add the ndarray dependencies in cargo.toml file. Here is the rust file gist link. However, I got 2 errors that I posted in that gist comment. May I know how to fix that? Thanks

@ardiantovn: The first error is pretty self-explanatory, is it not?  And the second error appears to be the same as in your question here, which would be fixed by following the instructions in my answer.  Have you added the ndarray feature to the matfile dependency in your Cargo.toml?  It would help if you showed the contents of your Cargo.toml since that is the likely source of this error.

Hi @eggyal, thanks for your guide. I added  a comment on that gist link. There I tried to fix the first error in main.rs file, show the cargo.toml file, and errors that I got.

I just updated the code in gist link. Now the code works, however I wonder why the Rust said "Error: Array types are not compatible" after converting the array. I have tried to declare the array type in rust equals to array type that I got from python.

solved. I just found that the data type should be complex eventhough the data type in python is numpy.complex64. Thanks @eggyal for your help...
